# Prevent an app from opening other apps ios

Tags: ios

Does anyone know what it takes to make an iOS app that prevents users from opening other apps?

Example: The app should be able to prevent the user from opening apps like browsers, mail clients, or games.

I'm not talking about apps that restrict features of the device, like Apple's own restrictions in Settings. I'm talking about an app that prevents other app from running.

Comment: Are you talking about an app to be sold on the App Store or an app you install on a local device to be run in kiosk mode?

Comment: I'm talking about an app to be sold on the App Store.

Comment: No, can't be done.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for quick reply. Could you provide some documentation that says it can't be done?

Comment: There are no docs that say it can't be done. There's no API for such a thing. There are only docs for what an app can do, not for what it can't do.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your replies. I had a feeling that it would violate Apple's guidelines, but wanted to hear more from experienced developers.

Comment: It's not that it violates their guidelines (though it probably would). It's that there is no API for it. You simply can't write code that blocks other apps.

Comment: Perhaps not with an API, but the app Kidslox on the App Store actually prevents apps from use by hiding them. They use Apple Mobile Device Management to do this. However, the app cannot hide all apps.